# Guava Dependency Breaking Jar Built With Kotlin

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, guava, android-guava

## Issue

The Java/Kotlin application runs as expected in from the Main Class in IntelliJ's IDE. However, when the app is built into  a **.Jar** file the following error occurs: `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors`.

This is an issue with refactoring the directory, module, root project, and/or group names.

## Reproducing Error

I've moved the project to a new directory path and everything runs as expected. However, after I attempt to modify the directory, and/or module names and refactor the `rootProject.name` in *settings.gradle* and the `group` in the *build.gradle* is when the error above appears when running a new **.jar** build.

### Full Error Message

```
Exception in thread "Timer-0" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor()Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;
at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.<init>(ClientCallImpl.java:96)
at io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl$RealChannel.newCall(ManagedChannelImpl.java:662)
at io.grpc.internal.CensusTracingModule$TracingClientInterceptor.interceptCall(CensusTracingModule.java:382)
at io.grpc.ClientInterceptors$InterceptorChannel.newCall(ClientInterceptors.java:104)
at io.grpc.internal.CensusStatsModule$StatsClientInterceptor.interceptCall(CensusStatsModule.java:675)
at io.grpc.ClientInterceptors$InterceptorChannel.newCall(ClientInterceptors.java:104)
at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcHeaderInterceptor.interceptCall(GrpcHeaderInterceptor.java:81)
at io.grpc.ClientInterceptors$InterceptorChannel.newCall(ClientInterceptors.java:104)
at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcMetadataHandlerInterceptor.interceptCall(GrpcMetadataHandlerInterceptor.java:55)
at io.grpc.ClientInterceptors$InterceptorChannel.newCall(ClientInterceptors.java:104)
at io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl.newCall(ManagedChannelImpl.java:636)
at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcClientCalls.newCall(GrpcClientCalls.java:66)
at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcDirectCallable.futureCall(GrpcDirectCallable.java:58)
at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcExceptionCallable.futureCall(GrpcExceptionCallable.java:62)
at com.google.api.gax.rpc.UnaryCallable$1.futureCall(UnaryCallable.java:126)
at com.google.api.gax.rpc.UnaryCallable.futureCall(UnaryCallable.java:87)
at com.google.cloud.firestore.FirestoreImpl.sendRequest(FirestoreImpl.java:330)
at com.google.cloud.firestore.UpdateBuilder.commit(UpdateBuilder.java:608)
at com.google.cloud.firestore.WriteBatch.commit(WriteBatch.java:41)
at com.google.cloud.firestore.DocumentReference.create(DocumentReference.java:141)
at com.google.cloud.firestore.CollectionReference.add(CollectionReference.java:115)
at com.google.cloud.firestore.CollectionReference.add(CollectionReference.java:141)
at PriceDifferenceTask.findMaxProfitAndPercentPriceDifference(PriceDifferenceTask.kt:167)
at PriceDifferenceTask.access$findMaxProfitAndPercentPriceDifference(PriceDifferenceTask.kt:15)
at PriceDifferenceTask$run$1.call(PriceDifferenceTask.kt:64)
at PriceDifferenceTask$run$1.call(PriceDifferenceTask.kt:15)
at rx.functions.Functions$6.call(Functions.java:169)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorZip$Zip.tick(OperatorZip.java:252)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorZip$Zip$InnerSubscriber.onNext(OperatorZip.java:323)
at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$WeakSingleProducer.request(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:276)
at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:211)
at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$JustOnSubscribe.call(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:138)
at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$JustOnSubscribe.call(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:129)
at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10256)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorZip$Zip.start(OperatorZip.java:202)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorZip$ZipSubscriber.onNext(OperatorZip.java:143)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorZip$ZipSubscriber.onNext(OperatorZip.java:109)
at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$WeakSingleProducer.request(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:276)
at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:209)
at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$JustOnSubscribe.call(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:138)
at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$JustOnSubscribe.call(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:129)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10352)
at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10319)
at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10159)
at PriceDifferenceTask.run(PriceDifferenceTask.kt:66)
at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
```

## Implementation

### build.gradle

```
group 'coinverse'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.71'
    ext.junitJupiterVersion  = '5.0.3'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-gradle-plugin:1.0.3'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'kotlin'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
    testImplementation group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    // JUnit Jupiter API and TestEngine implementation
    testCompile("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:${junitJupiterVersion}")
    testRuntime("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:${junitJupiterVersion}")
    testCompile("org.assertj:assertj-core:3.10.0")
    // To avoid compiler warnings about @API annotations in JUnit code
    testCompileOnly('org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:1.0.0')
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.4.0'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:6.5.0'
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
```

### [Gradle Dependency Tree](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1dEafyFrd97WbPQ7diPFyqlWpwBVeXH11chtyRQh4udk/edit?usp=sharing)

## Attempted Solutions

1. After examining similar issues on StackOverflow this appears to be related to a conflict with Google's Guava library. From the Gradle Dependencies above some libraries were calling older versions of Guava. All libraries in the *build.gradle* have been updated to their latest versions.
2. Rebuilding project.
3. IntelliJ Invalidate Cache and Restart
4. Implementing current version of Guava in *build.gradle*: `api "com.google.guava:guava:27.0-jre"`
5. Implementing lowest version of Guava in *build.gradle* found in dependency tree: `implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:19.0'`
6. Implementing highest version of Guava in *build.gradle* found in dependency tree: `implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:20.0'`
7. Attempting to exclude lowest version of Guava in *build.gradle* found in dependency tree: `configurations {all*.exclude 'com.google.guava:guava:19.0'}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

The **Jar** build started working again after updating my library dependencies and redefining the Project level SDK when re-pulling a version built on a different machine from Github.

### Update to dependencies

1. Changed `compile` to `implementation`.
2. Updated version numbers by searching for each project's latest version on Google.

### build.grade

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.10'
    ext.junitJupiterVersion  = '5.3.2'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-gradle-plugin:1.0.3'
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.2.51'
}

version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8"
    testImplementation group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '5.3.2'
    // JUnit Jupiter API and TestEngine implementation
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:${junitJupiterVersion}")
    testRuntime("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:${junitJupiterVersion}")
    testImplementation "org.assertj:assertj-core:3.11.1"
    // To avoid compiler warnings about @API annotations in JUnit code
    testCompileOnly 'org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.5.0'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:6.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev206-1.25.0'
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

add the current version `27.0`:

```
dependencies {
    api "com.google.guava:guava:27.0-jre"
}
```

and `exclude` both other versions `19.0` and `20.0`, wherever they may be referenced.

```
./gradlew app:dependencies > dependencies.txt
```

or check with:

```
./gradlew app:dependencies | grep guava
```

for example (the `firebase-admin` is certainly a candidate):

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.firebase/firebase-admin
implementation ("com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:6.5.0") {
    exclude group: "com.google.guava", module: "guava"
}
```

there may be further references present.

Comment: I've updated to the latest version of Guava as recommended as well as excluded the following from **firebase-admin** `"com.google.guava", module: "guava"`. I am not able to successfully execute the command you suggested `./gradlew app:dependencies | grep guava`. The error is: `Project 'app' not found in root project 'coinverse-price'.`

Comment: @AdamHurwitz you need to replace `app:` with the name of the module, eg. `mobile:`; or even remove it, in case there are no modules in root project `coinverse-price`.

Comment: Here is the [result of the working **dependencies** command](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ukNE9FGbjDnrYjPU9j1bjTrDfPBQlifuURJh7iK2kFk/edit?usp=sharing). It does not look like there are further conflicts, however the **Jar** throws the same error when attempting to run.

Comment: @AdamHurwitz cannot access the file. but `com.google.api.gax.grpc` might be another candidate, which needs `guava` excluded on whatever module depends on it. all occurrences of `guava` should point to `27.0`... with plugin `java` it might be `27.0-jre` instead of `27.0-android`.

Comment: Sorry about that! You now have access to the [document](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ukNE9FGbjDnrYjPU9j1bjTrDfPBQlifuURJh7iK2kFk/edit?usp=sharing). I've added `implementation ('com.google.api.gax.grpc') {
        exclude group: "com.google.guava", module: "guava"
    }` for good measure. Unfortunately the issue is still present.

Comment: the log does not appear to be complete, because some dependencies do not show their transitive dependencies. `./gradlew dependencyInsight --configuration releaseCompileClasspath --dependency com.google.guava` would also list all occurrences.