# IntelliJ Main Error Migrating Projects: Exception in thread "Timer-0"

Tags: java, gradle, kotlin, intellij-idea, jar

## Overview

There is an issue when attempting to migrate a Kotlin AppEngine project from an old MacBook Pro (MBP) to a new MBP, when running the `Main` method and building a *.jar* file locally.

The `Main` method in IntelliJ fails intermittently on the new MBP. The old *.jar* runs as expected on the new MBP, and the new *.jar* runs as expected on the old MBP.

**Expected**

1. Run existing local *.jar* file from Kotlin project on the old MBP.
2. Clone Kotlin project from GitHub repository into local IntelliJ project on new MBP.
3. Build *.jar* on new MBP.
4. Run *.jar* on new MBP.
5. Host *.jar* on Google AppEngine instance.

**Observed**

1. Running *.jar* on existing MBP works as expected.
2. Running `main` method with the same code runs intermittently on the new MBP after the GitHub repo is cloned locally.

## Error

**The `Main` method runs on the old MBP as expected, but not on the new MBP with the following error.**

> Exception in thread "Timer-0" com.google.cloud.storage.StorageException: 401 Unauthorized
>       at com.google.cloud.storage.spi.v1.HttpStorageRpc.translate(HttpStorageRpc.java:229)
>       at com.google.cloud.storage.spi.v1.HttpStorageRpc.create(HttpStorageRpc.java:310)
>       at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl$3.call(StorageImpl.java:196)
>       at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl$3.call(StorageImpl.java:193)
>       at com.google.api.gax.retrying.DirectRetryingExecutor.submit(DirectRetryingExecutor.java:105)
>       at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.run(RetryHelper.java:76)
>       at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.runWithRetries(RetryHelper.java:50)
>       at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl.internalCreate(StorageImpl.java:192)
>       at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl.create(StorageImpl.java:154)
>       at content.SaveContentKt.saveContent(SaveContent.kt:38)
>       at content.ContentTasks.generateContent(ContentTasks.kt:55)
>       at content.ContentTasks.run(ContentTasks.kt:41)
>       at java.base/java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:556)
>       at java.base/java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:506)
>   Caused by: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 401 Unauthorized
>       at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:150)
>       at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
>       at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
>       at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:554)
>       at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:474)
>       at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:591)
>       at com.google.cloud.storage.spi.v1.HttpStorageRpc.create(HttpStorageRpc.java:307)
>       ... 12 more

### Configuration

The *gradle-wrapper.properties* **Gradle**, IntelliJ Preferences **Gradle JVM**, Project **SDK**, Run/Debug Configurations **JRE**, and Project **language level** versions are the same across both machines.

*Preferences* > *Gradle*

- *Use Gradle from:* `'gradle-wrapper.properties' file`
- *Gradle JVM:* `Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/12.0.1`

*File* > *Project Structure...* > *Project*

- *Project SDK:* `12.0.1`
- *Project language level:* `11`

*Running .jar file*: *Project Structure* > *Project Settings* > *Artifacts* > *Add* > *JAR* > *From modules with dependencies...*

- *Module:* `coinverse-media.main`
- *Main Class:* `Initialization`

Lastly, build artifact and run *.jar* file.

*build.gradle*

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.61'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.2.51'
}

version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8"
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.7.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.7.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.7.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:6.12.0'
    implementation 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-storage:1.102.0'
    implementation 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev20190827-1.30.1'
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
```

## Attempted Solutions

1. *Invalidate Caches / Restart...*: This appears to fix the issue for a few times running the `Main` method, then the error continues to show.
2. `./gradlew clean build`
3. Gradle > Reimport All Gradle Projects
4. Updating to the latest [Gradle version](https://gradle.org/releases/).
5. Ensure existing MBP and new MBP are running on the same IntelliJ/Project/Run configurations.
6. Potentially related build dependency conflict issue: [Guava Dependency Breaking Jar Built With Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52881622/guava-dependency-breaking-jar-built-with-kotlin).

## Build Data

- [Build scan results](https://scans.gradle.com/s/exa2ynrifkfua)
- Stack trace

> 6:09:42 PM: Executing task 'assemble'...
>
> Task :compileKotlin UP-TO-DATE
>
> Task :compileJava NO-SOURCE
>
> Task :processResources NO-SOURCE
>
> Task :classes UP-TO-DATE
>
> Task :inspectClassesForKotlinIC UP-TO-DATE
>
> Task :jar UP-TO-DATE
>
> Task :assemble UP-TO-DATE
>
> BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 75ms
>   3 actionable tasks: 3 up-to-date
>   6:09:42 PM: Task execution finished 'assemble'.

- Hidden files
  [image]

Comment: Have you determined whether the problem is with the new .jar or running on the new Mac? (i.e. does the old .jar run on the new Mac or the new .jar fail on the old Mac?)

BTW, a 401 code seems like an HTTP authentication problem. Check for hidden files (starting with `.` use `ls -la` to see them) which could impact either the building of the .jar or running of the .jar file. Similarly for environment variables. If you're running the .jar inside IntelliJ the run configuration there also applies.

Comment: @kamakaze, The main issue is running the `Main` method in IntelliJ on the new Mac. The old *.jar* runs as expected on the new Mac, and the new *.jar* compiled yesterday runs as expected on the old Mac. **The `Main` method runs on the old Mac as expected, but not on the new Mac.**

Comment: So would you agree that the problem is with the run configuration (and not the build configuration) in IntelliJ on the new Mac? If that's the case visually compare the project settings (especially the run configuration) between the old and new mac.

Comment: @karmakaze, Good point. I think there is a high likelihood the issue is with the run configuration. I've re-checked the IntelliJ, Project, and Run configurations. The *gradle-wrapper.properties* **Gradle**, IntelliJ Preferences **Gradle JVM**, Project **SDK**, Run/Debug Configurations **JRE**, and Project **language level** versions are the same across both machines.

Comment: @karmakaze, May you also vote on the question in order to help others discover this, who are also having this issue.

Comment: It seems more of an IntelliJ config issue than GCP one. Maybe update the title to be something that seems relevant to the current knowledge.

Comment: @karmakaze, The title change is complete.

Comment: @karmakaze, The fact that the issue temporarily subsides after _Invalidate cache/Restart..._ seems to be a clue...